# Meaning of a Jean Paul Sartre's saying

Tags: terminology

Could you please what does Sartre mean when he says that:"freedom alone can account for a person in his totality."? And what does "account" mean in this sentence?

Comment: Philosophy really isn't how you want to be learning English dude

Comment: This is probably a question for http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/. "Account for" means "give a satisfactory record of" (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/account).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it (probably) belongs on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Silenus ~ I doubt even the philosophy board would understand what Sartre was trying to say here, or that Sartre himself even understands it. It's a translation of a French philosopher who obfuscates reality instead of elucidating it.

Comment: It is n't just philosophy, it 's an English sentence too. If you have no answer,you can just say "I do n't know"

Comment: @hooshmand ~ have you tried looking up the definitions of "account for" and "totality"? The problem isn't with knowing the definitions of these terms; the problem is that the main idea of the sentence itself is absolute pseudo-intellectual drivel.

Comment: @Silenus, I see. Thank you so much. But V0ight answered me impolitely.

Comment: Here is an analysis of the Sartre passage: https://books.google.com/books?id=eLg6rsGBPTwC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=freedom+alone+can+account+for+a+person+sartre&source=bl&ots=ATkBpmDtI_&sig=ZCN1Bi8Nw6EvXGzankmxCb6lL1o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL29Sw7IzOAhVBaD4KHanLA8EQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=freedom%20alone%20can%20account%20for%20a%20person%20sartre&f=false. It seems like Sartre made this comment in a larger discussion of genius. The rough idea seems to be that "Freedom alone explains genius," or "Those people we call geniuses are really just people who are acting completely free of limitations."

Comment: @Silenus ~ and what does *that* mean? ;)

Comment: Dear Silenus, as you remarked it relates to genius. Yet i can not get the sentence's meaning - specially the meaning of "account" or "account for".

Comment: Among other things, it's likely that Sartre wrote that in French and the sentence has been translated to English by someone else.  It would make more sense to identify the French source sentence and ask about that on a French web site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the quote is provided without identifying any context.

Comment: Someone had voted to close it before but as the discussion developed he liked it and he is chatting me know. And what about you? Try it and open your heart to the teamworking.

Comment: V0ight, despite his great aversion to Sartre, explained "account for" in his answer, as did Silenus in his comments.   (Account for, in this context, has nothing to do with arithmetic.)  As for the meaning of the entire sentence, it is beyond me.  Even with context, it would be beyond me.

Answer (score 3):

[image] http://www.dictionary.com/browse/account--for

---

In the sense used in this sentence, "account for" means "to be the determining factor for, or cause of".

Therefore Sartre is saying that freedom is the sole factor for determining a person's total genius. How Sartre supports this statement, however, remains a mystery.

---

Comment: Dear V0ight,"totality" in the sentence refers to "person" not "genius". Moreover I think you lost the original sentence.So your meaning "freedom is the sole ..." can not be true.

Comment: @hooshmand ~ what original sentence? I can only work with what you've provided me. And as you can see from Silenus's link, the subject is "genius", and therefore "person" is referring to his intellect or genius in this case.

Comment: The original sentece is "freedom elone can account for a person in his totality". True, genius is the main discussion, but the subject of the original sentence is freedom. There is no mentioning to "genius" in it. So my question - the meaning of the sentence - mains still without answer.yet I thank you because you didn't leave me alone and try to help me.

Comment: @hooshman ~ Like I said then, probably even Sartre doesn't know what he's talking about in this sentence, or the translation is faulty. Keep in mind, the original is in French.